# What will the be the effect(s) of adding 20 to the code?

Tags: c#, random

So this subroutine simulates the rolling of a 12-sided dice. The code works fine as it is below but I'm told that if I write **"Random Number = new Random(20);"** instead of **"Random Number = new Random();"** it will change the output somehow. I'm not sure what modifying it to 20 will even do?

```
// Number data types
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        // Subroutine to generate a random number
        static int RollDice()
        {
            Random Number = new Random();
            return Number.Next(1,13);
        }
        //Main program
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Dice = RollDice();
            Console.WriteLine("Rolled a {0}", Dice);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could try it......... and you could read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-5.0

Comment: @MitchWheat I observed no change in the output

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=net-5.0   :"Random(Int32) 
Initializes a new instance of the Random class, using the specified seed value."

Comment: A seed value is so that you can reproduce the sequence of random numbers. You might want to do this when writing unit tests, or persisting a game's state, for example.

Comment: Google : `c# random`. Look for constructor with 1 parameter, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Random__ctor_System_Int32_ discover the concept of seed in random generator. Google : `random generator seed`. Read the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed **learn something by yourself** without spending SO user's time.

Comment: as other wrote ... here is example which could help you understand what would happend https://dotnetfiddle.net/c6twdU

Answer (score 1):

That would be the random seed. The fact that you don't notice a difference means that it's a good implementation of `Random`, and the result are really evenly distributed.

One thing you should notice though is that by not passing an argument to `Random`'s constructor, the seed would be derived from the system clock. This means the subsequent executions of the program should produce a different series of "random" results. On the other hand, if you hard code the random seed (e.g., to 20), every execution of the program will produce the same series of numbers.